# How to solve Alignment problem in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css, create-react-app

[image: image of present problem]

How to bring the menu button and CarFix in a single line? Below is my react js code of top navigation component.

```
import React from 'react'
import {AiOutlineMenu, AiOutlineSearch, AiOutlineClose, AiFillTag} from 'react-icons/ai'

const TopNav = () => {
  return (
    <div className="max-w-[1520px] mx-auto flex justify-between items-center p-4">
    <div className="flex items-center">
      <div  className="cursor-pointer">
        <AiOutlineMenu size={25} />
      </div>
      <h1 className="text-2xl sm:text-3xl lg:text-4xl px-2">
        Car
        <span className="font-bold">Fix</span>
      </h1>
            </div>
    </div>
  )
}
export default TopNav
```

Comment: Should be a single line [as per this Tailwind Play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/1dMDW7YI9j), which would suggest there is some other problem in your project.

Comment: @Wongjn what could it be? Any suggestions where to look?

Comment: @Wongjn Could this be a warning 'Unknown at rule' in the below code which is put in index.css 
`
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer base {
  button{
    @apply border border-black rounded-xl px-5 py-1
  }
}
`

Comment: Inspect the elements in the browser. There you can detect what is causing the problem. That ```Car``` in ```CarFix``` is bold, but it should be normal font-weight. Seems like those class names don't apply any styles

Comment: @Wongjn How to know if tailwind css is running with react js or not?

Answer (score 1):

**A solution to this problem can be achieved by creating a div that contains the h1 and applying flex to it.**

Here is the updated code.

```
import React from 'react';
import { AiOutlineMenu } from 'react-icons/ai';

const TopNav = () => {
  return (
    <div className="max-w-[1520px] mx-auto flex justify-between items-center p-4">
      <div className="flex items-center">
        <div className="cursor-pointer">
          <AiOutlineMenu size={25} />
        </div>
        <div className="cursor-pointer flex items-center"> {/* New div with cursor-pointer */}
          <h1 className="text-2xl sm:text-3xl lg:text-4xl px-2">
            Car
            <span className="font-bold">Fix</span>
          </h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TopNav;
```

Comment: Problem still exist after applying this code.